# Using Xamarin Forms for Android and IOS, how to display a status indicator for 4 unique states

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For Xamarin Forms for Android and IOS, how do I display a status indicator (not an activity indicator) showing up to 4 unique states of the server, data or other objects, all set in the code behind with binded objects/strings/ints?

Skia sharp and RoundedBoxView are two libraries that I've found, however they're significantly more complex to implement that I was hoping for.

Essentially what I'm looking for is to display one of the following in a grid:

- Error (Red)
- Warning (Yellow)
- No problems (Green)
- Other/TBD (Grey)

Thank you for your time and assistance. The answer MUST be in Xamarin.Forms instead of native platform specific. I also greatly prefer something that already exists in Xamarin.Forms instead of getting another library and implementing it but not opposed to it.

Comment: I have also tried using photos but they don't work. Other photos work though so I don't know why.  Even when using the same methods and the only difference is the name of the file/resource.

Comment: Just had an idea: change the relevant background color of the entire cell. this would require a ListViewTemplateSelector. has anyone implemented this successfully? if so is there an example i may use.

Comment: What kind of **status indicator** do you want, you can upload an image to show it.`ActivityIndicator` binding model also can achieve different colors.

Comment: ActivityIndicator can do other colors? Ok. But is there a way to disable the animation and fill it so its solid. A colored circle is what im looking for.

Comment: Yeah, `<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" IsVisible="True" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
 Color="Aqua">`Using Color property can do that.If want a special view, you need to custom them in native .You can show a sample image,it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I display a status indicator (not an activity indicator) showing up to 4 unique states of the server, data or other objects, all set in the code behind with binded objects/strings/ints?
>
> But is there a way to disable the animation and fill it so its solid.

If just want to display a **Solid circle**, then the **BoxView** can also do it and change the color.

1. Set `CornerRadius` property of BoxView can show as a circle .
2. Just binding `Color` property of BoxView to ViewModel,and converting the value of Color by `IValueConverter`.
3. If want color dynamic changed, also need to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` in ViewModel.

**Xmal** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:PickerCase="clr-namespace:PickerCase" //PickerCase is project namespace
         x:Class="PickerCase.NextPage"> //NextPage is current page name

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <PickerCase:StringToColorConverter x:Key="StringToColorConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <BoxView Color="{Binding MyColor, Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 WidthRequest="40"
                 HeightRequest="40"
                 CornerRadius="20"/>
    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

Creating a **StringToColorConverter.cs** file to convert color by string value:

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    string valueAsString = value.ToString();
    switch (valueAsString)
    {
        case ("Red"):
            {
                return Color.Red;
            }
        case ("Yellow"):
            {
                return Color.Yellow;
            }
        case ("Green"):
            {
                return Color.Green;
            }
        case ("Gray"):
            {
                return Color.Gray;
            }
        default:
            {
                return Color.FromHex(value.ToString());
            }
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    return null;
}
}
```

**ViewModel** add `MyColor` property ,and `OnPropertyChanged` it.

```
class SecondDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private string mycolor = "Gray"; //Default color is Gray

    public string MyColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (mycolor != value)
            {
                mycolor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyColor");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return mycolor;
        }
    }


    public SecondDataModel()
    {

    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Finally in **ContentPage** bind this ViewModel:

```
 SecondDataModel secondDataModel;
 ...
 secondDataModel = new SecondDataModel();
 BindingContext = secondDataModel;
```

When the data from API Server, you can change color as follow:

```
secondDataModel.MyColor = "Red";
...
secondDataModel.MyColor = "Yelow";
...
secondDataModel.MyColor = "Green";
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's giving the Error:  'PickerCase' is an undeclared prefix.

Comment: `PickerCase` is My project name, this need to change to yours. I update answer about adding code and note.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative/slightly different implementation to Junior Jiang's solution is to have a Converter which converts to an Image rather than converting colours. You can then have a different Image asset for each status.

*Note* using an ActivityIndicator would be horrible! The implementation on different platforms is different, and would just not look right.